# Prove if this inequality holds true

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $N\in\mathbb{N}, N\ge 2$ and $p, q\in\mathbb{R}, 1<q<p<N$ and also $q>\frac{N(p-1)}{(N-1)}$.
Under these assumptions, it is true that
$$\frac{N-p}{p}- \frac{N(p-1)(p-q)}{p^2}>0?$$
I proceeded by trial so far, but I need to prove if it always true or not.

Could someone please help with that equation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your posting to show your efforts.

Comment: What is the source and motivation for this Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True. Multiplying by $p^2,$ the inequality is $$(*)...\quad p(N-p)>N(p-1)(p-q).$$ Let the RHS of $(*)$ be $F(q).$ Now $F(q)$ is a strictly decreasing continuous function of $q.$ And we have $1<q$ and $\frac {N(p-1)}{N-1}<q.$ So $(*)$ holds if $p(N-p)\ge F(q')$ where $q'=\max (1,\frac {N(p-1)}{N-1} \,).$

Case $(1).$  If $q'=1$. Then $F(q')=F(1)=N(p-1)^2$. But also $$q'=1\implies 1\ge \frac {N(p-1)}{N-1}\implies p-1\le\frac {N-1}{N} \implies$$ $$\implies  F(q')=N(p-1)^2\le N\cdot\frac { (N-1)^2}{N^2}=$$ $$=\frac {(N-1)^2}{N}<N-1<p(N-p).$$ The last inequality above is because if $G(p)=p(N-p)$ then $1<p<N \implies G(p)>G(1)=N-1.$

Case $(2).$ If $q'=\frac {N(p-1)}{N-1}.$ Then $F(q')=N(p-1)\left(p-N\cdot \frac {p-1}{N-1}\right)=\dfrac {N(p-1)(N-p)}{N-1}.$

So now we have $$F(q')\le p(N-p)\iff \dfrac {N(p-1)(N-p)}{N-1}\le p(N-p)\iff$$ $$\iff \dfrac {N(p-1)}{N-1} \le p\iff$$ $$\iff \frac {p-1}{p}\le \frac {N-1}{N} \iff p\le N.$$